# Sinch - Accumulated call established time

Tags: ios, sinch

Is it possible to get the accumulated call established time based on a unique user?

I couldn't find that piece of info in the dashboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information is not available in the Sinch Dashboard but will be accessible via a REST API. As a partner, you will also have the possibility to download Call Detail Records (CDR) files that can be used to gather those metrics.

Both option will be released shortly when the Sinch REST APIs (http://www.sinch.com/docs/rest-apis/) are made available.